# Started Service stops if application is forcestop from download App

Tags: android, eclipse

i made a sample android app,which starts a started service by calling startService(serviceintent).

it works fine,but if i forceQuit my application from settings>app>downloaded>force_Quit.my service stops and even destroyed is not called.
i studied for 3-4 days and know about start_sticky in StartOnCommand method.i am able to achieve all aspects of service.

I want to know whatever i am achieving that service stops and doesnot restart automatically even if started as Start_Sticky is normal behaviour according to android.Can i make it restared if user force quit my application.

my manifest is correct i uses process tag also.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022985/restart-service-after-force-stop ?

Answer (score 1):

> if i forceQuit my application from settings>app>downloaded>force_Quit.my service stops and even destroyed is not called.

Correct.

> Can i make it restared if user force quit my application.

No. Nothing of your app will run again until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. Usually, that means that the user taps on your icon in the home screen launcher, though there are other explicit-`Intent` scenarios (e.g., GCM message).

Comment: thanks commonsware,but dnt get annoyed,can you give any link of Android document,that proofs your saying.

Comment: @DharmendraChaudhary: The only documentation on this that I know of is the "Launch Controls on Stopped Applications" section of [the Android 3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).