# keep notification after clean memory android?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

after clear memory:
 - All service what running in background was killed.
 - All notification was removed.
so :
 - How to restart service or keep it running in background after clean memory or was killed.
 - How to keep notification after clean memory.
 I see some application not in whitelist but it can restart service after killed

my device: OPPO os: 5.1.1

Comment: Clean memory can be a force kill which in the end kills the whole app's process to free up system memory used by the app. I don't think any app will be immune to a process kill.

Comment: It is a feature called **push notifications** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022985/restart-service-after-force-stop

Comment: i see has 1 app of my country which was received FCM notification after clean memory(it not work after force stop). i don't how they can keep service or app running(chathead) after clean. in my app, all was killed.

Comment: @NguyễnThànhDuy got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `START_STICKY`, in method `onStartCommand()`. [Here is more information](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_STICKY).

[Examples, with descriptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

Comment: thank for your reply , i have use START_STICKY in onStartCommand() but not work.  i use sendBroadcast() on onTaskRemoved() and onDestroy() to restart , it not work. i try alarmservice but not work. i see in logs when clean memory, all method not call. service, IntentService, AlarmService, BroadcastReceiver was killed after clean memory.

Comment: How do you clean memory?

Comment: OPPO device has "Security Center". it has Clean up & accelerate that will clean up memory and cache junk file.