# How to automatically restart a service even if user force close it?

Tags: android, service, alarm

I want a service to run all the time in my application. So I want to restart it even if it is force closed by user. There is definitely a way to do it as apps like facebook are doing it. It's not done using push notification, facebook restarts its service even if internet is off.

Comment: are you using background service...

Comment: Make another service which which will start the first one or make a reciever which on any event checks if the service is available, if not, it will start it.

Comment: You may want your service to run all the time, but the fact that your users are force closing it means they don't. If the app is meant for public use, please reconsider this requirement

Comment: which answer resolved your problem finally ?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 71):

First of all, it is **really very bad pattern** to run service forcefully **against the user's willingness**.

Anyways, you can restart it by using a `BroadcastReceiver` which handles the broadcast sent from `onDestroy()` of your service.

**StickyService.java**

```
public class StickyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "StickyService";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("YouWillNeverKillMe"));
    }

}
```

**RestartServiceReceiver.java**

```
public class RestartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    private static final String TAG = "RestartServiceReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive");
    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), StickyService.class));

    }

}
```

Declare the **components in manifest** file:

```
    <service android:name=".StickyService" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".RestartServiceReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="YouWillNeverKillMe" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Start the `StickyService` in a Component (i.e. `Application`, `Activity`, `Fragment`):

```
startService(new Intent(this, StickyService.class));
```

OR

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("YouWillNeverKillMe"));
```

Comment: Agree, it is. But have to do it.

Comment: This does not work for me. Nothing seems to work actually. I tried using an AlarmManager triggered service as well.

Comment: @Sohaib: it is working fine for me. can u provide more info about your case? android version, code etc.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29607856/1901744.
Android version is 4.4.4.

Comment: As far as I know if user force stops an application BroadcastReceivers won't work anymore

Comment: A SOLUTION that would work even if onDestroy isn't called everytime: send a broadcast from your service every one second and create a receiver that receives those broadcasts. Get the ellapsed time since the last broadcast message. If it is (a lot) greater than 1 second then your service isn't alive anymore -> restart it. Hope this helps

Comment: @sjkm Isn't that battery killer?

Comment: @joaquin Hi, no it is not really. A call every one second or few seconds is nothing. You probably won't notice anything...

Comment: if we force stop the app , no instance of app there in the device, then where you calculate the elapsed time? one solution i found is ping server from service , and check the ping is getting every time interval , if the ping stops,  send a gcm notification from server, and on receiving the gcm broadcast restart the service. but it is very costly and comlex

Comment: @sjkm i am pretty sure it won't work. the logic is good, but won't work. Could you say where you calculating ( _If it is (a lot) greater than 1 second then your service isn't alive anymore -> restart it_ ) and restarting the service again ?

Comment: Since Android 3.1, apps that are in the stopped state do not receive 
broadcast Intents, nor gcm push messages.

Comment: what if I start the same service again from there without broadcasting ?

Comment: Not working when user force close the app. **onDestroy** isn't called.

Comment: "First of all, it is really very bad pattern to run service forcefully against the user's willingness." -> that s what Google do all time...

Comment: In some phones like Mi and Vivo, we have to change the settings and give the app special permission to run in background from the settings app. Even if you have made a service that auto-restarts when the app is closed, the service won't run until and unless you set permissions in the settings app of your phone.

Comment: Try it with `adb shell am crash [my_pid]`

Answer (score 17):

You have to create a `sticky service` with overriding `onTaskRemoved` method, where you can set an alarm service to trigger your code again.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //create an intent that you want to start again.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, pendingIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```

Also in some devices like Xiaomi, Huwaei the app gets force closed once it's removed from recent apps. This is because the manufacturers have task manager features which improve ram/battery performance.

You can check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360159/2798289

Answer (score 5):

As per the Android document

```
Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of applications 
that are in a stopped state and provides a means of controlling their launch from 
background processes and other applications.

Note that an application's stopped state is not the same as an Activity's stopped
state. The system manages those two stopped states separately.
FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped applications in the
list of potential targets to resolve against.

FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Exclude intent filters of stopped applications from the
list of potential targets.

When neither or both of these flags is defined in an intent, the default behavior is to
include filters of stopped applications in the list of potential targets. 

Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents.
It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or
unnecessarily launching components of stopped applications. A background service 
or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications.
```

On Force stop of app, Android just kill the process ID. No warnings, callbacks are given to service/activities. As per the Android document, When the app is killed there are chances that it calls onPause().

When I tried in my app, even onPause() was not called. I think the only way is use to `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` intent flag and send it from another app

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, then actually this is not possible, Android feature to force close application was designed to allow user to get rid of unwanted applications, so it disallows any activities from it until user again starts any of its Activity.

[Restart the service even if app is force-stopped and Keep running service in background even after closing the app   How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671460/restart-the-service-even-if-app-is-force-stopped-and-keep-running-service-in-bac)

Comment: It is, as I mentioned other apps are doing it

Comment: It appears that KitKat brought some changes in this matter, look in here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac. Author workaround is: "The workaround I'm using is very simple: I create a transparent activity from onTaskRemoved to restart my services. How dirtier can it get?"

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a service is killed, its `onDestroy` method is always called.
Its better to use a **BroadcastReceiver** to start your service when it is killed.

Here is a sample code illustrating its implementation:-

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setAction("StartkilledService");
sendBroadcast(in);
Log.d("debug", "Service Killed");
}
```

Then register a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`:-

```
<receiver android:name=".app.ServiceDestroyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="StartKilledService" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Finally,create a **BroadcastReceiver**,and start your service in the `onReceive` method:-

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.d("debug", "ServeiceDestroy onReceive...");
Log.d("debug", "action:" + intent.getAction());
Log.d("debug", "Starting Service");
ServiceManager.startService();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: onDestroy() doesn't get called everytime. Tried it.

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672438/start-service-after-force-stop

Comment: If you force stop your service, the process is killed immediately and no callback sent to it. So onDestroy is not called.

Comment: call stopService when the app is killed (i.e. on the app's onDestroy method). This will work

Comment: "Whenever a service is killed, its onDestroy method is always called." - this is a lie

Answer (score 2):

on the service's startCommand method return START_STICKY. generally it tell the OS to start the service when it is killed.

Comment: This works it android kills the service, not when we force close it.

Answer (score 2):

If the situation allows to use 'root' it's usually possible to implement Humpty-Dumpty paradigm.

Your application (1st) installs another application (2nd, taking APK from assets) and runs the service of the 2nd app. 
2nd app's service bind to the 1st app service and rebinds when disconnected. The 1st app does the same.

Sure it will not help when all apps are killed by some Free RAM or similar application but when Android kills either of those two, the other one will restart its counterpart.

Comment: github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler3

Comment: Is this a viable solution in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution for keeping services alive ist to call `Service.startForeground(...)` with a provided Notification. This will be the only valid solution, every other one will be very dependent on how Google will change the behaviour of it's system. With every API update, Google could prevent every other hack.

This also keeps the user aware, that your app is performing some background task which will keep the app alive and the user has to stop this. If you provide the user the ability to stop it is part of your application, though.

[See the Documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

```
void startForeground (int id, Notification notification)
```

> Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too much harm. You can set this flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as if your service is performing background music playback, so the user would notice if their music stopped playing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very hacky solution to keep service running even you force stop it. I do not recommend that because it is against user willingness. You can define a broadcast receiver to receive intent with action X. onStartCommand handler of your service, broadcast X (if the service is not started yet). on broadcast receiver upon receipt of X, first start the service, then, sleep for some minutes, and finally re-broadcast X.

Answer (score -1):

I think the only foolproof solution here is to have 2 services in separate processes (`android:process="somecustomprocessname"` in manifest, in the service entry) that both listen to broadcasts and restart each other, because currently the UI doesn't let users kill multiple processes in one action. You can then set up a pinger thread in each service that checks if the other service is running every 100 milliseconds or so, and if not, attempts to restart it. But this is starting to look more and more like malware...

Comment: This is malware from day 1 on. You simply shouldn't do that. Use Foreground Services for long living background work.

Comment: @da_berni I think people are supposed to read both the question, response and the date of both before throwing votes around.