# Get Mqtt notification even after app kill

Tags: android, notifications, mqtt, kill

I am implementing Mqtt to get push notification from server, getting connected successfully and getting notifications when app is open, and app is in background. but not getting push notification when app kill or close.
How should i implement my service and register Callback, don't no if AlaramManager and broadcast receiver are needed . Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 parts

1. First you need to make sure that you use persistent sessions, e.g. make sure you always use the same client id for a given client and you set the `cleanSession` flag to false so the broker will queue messages while the client is disconnected.
2. You need to make sure the service is restarted when it's killed, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550204/how-to-automatically-restart-a-service-even-if-user-force-close-it) should help

Comment: MqttCallBack is implemented for my service, i am starting service with flag START_STICKY, but not getting new message from Mqtt when app kills. is this like on killing of app  listener also killing?, how broadcast receiver work here?