# What the best Service launch type to upload data in this service in Android

Tags: android, service, background

I need to ulpoad data to a server in the `Service`?
As known Android system kills processes in case memory is low.
And any time my service can be killed till uploading wasn't finished?
How to avoid this trouble? 
I want to call `stopSelf()` when uploading finished.
What constant I have to use to avoid this?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_CONTINUATION_MASK

Answer (score 2):

> How to avoid this trouble? I want to call stopSelf() when uploading
>   finished. What constant I have to use to avoid this?

You can use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) which will automatically shutdown when task is completed.

> As known Android system kills processes in case memory is low. And any
>   time my service can be killed till uploading wasn't finished?

You can use [`startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#process-lifecycle) service as

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the `user is actively aware of and thus not a`
>   `candidate for killing when low on memory`.

For

> What constant I have to use to avoid this?

Use

`START_STICKY` : to restart the service once Killed (intent will be null on restart)

`START_REDELIVER_INTENT` : to restart the service once Killed and get the same intent back which was received first time

Note: very few devices does not follow the `START_STICKY` and similar instructions.

Reference:

[How to automatically restart a service even if user force close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550204/how-to-automatically-restart-a-service-even-if-user-force-close-it/21551045)

Comment: did u mean startForegroundService()?

Comment: Yes, it is the one the recommend solution for the situation otherwise, you use intent service and override `onlowmemory` if you can free some memory by setting null to references

Comment: a little trouble with this solution - min api = 26

Comment: which solution? startforegorund is available from API 5 use `startForeground (int id, 
                Notification notification)` and low memory is also from API 1